# How to calculate last leap year in sql sever?

Tags: sql-server-2012, powerbi

I need to calculate birthday count in one of my report. I know how to code to know a leap year but not able to write the code to use for finding the last leap year.

Please suggest some short code to get the last leap year.

Comment: what do you mean by the last leap year?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @fldYear INT=null
SET @fldYear = 2012
IF (((@fldYear % 4 = 0) AND (@fldYear % 100 != 0)) OR (@fldYear % 400 = 0))
PRINT '1'/*This is leap Year*/
ELSE
PRINT '0'/*This is not leap Year*/
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, using CTE I'm getting the last four years, and from the four years result, applying the leap year calculation to get the last leap year.

The working query is:

```
;WITH Last4Years AS (
     SELECT YEAR(GETDATE()) AS [YR]
     UNION ALL
     SELECT [YR] - 1
     FROM Last4Years 
     WHERE [YR] - 1 >= YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR, -3, GETDATE()))
)
SELECT [YR] AS LeapYear FROM (
    SELECT [YR], 
           CASE WHEN ([YR] % 4 = 0) AND ([YR] % 100 != 0) OR ([YR] % 400 = 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Leap
    FROM Last4Years 
) L 
WHERE Leap = 1;
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6a71df4faa833c2f32071b5ee34e003e)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the correct algo for "determine if the year is a leap year" is "log a bug with the platform that provided your date/datetime library because this is basic functionality that should have been exposed to the user".

Obviously they had to implement an "is leap year" check internally in their datetime/datetime2/datetimeoffset implementation, but somehow declined to expose it in their API because reasons.